# jquery - While loop for card game not working as intended

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making Blackjack just for fun/learning purposes. I've almost got it done, however I'm having an issue with the condition on which the player clicks "stand". It works except for the case where the player has a higher total than the dealer.

Say player has 19, while dealer has 15. Then player clicks "stand". It currently will only give the dealer one card wether the outcome results in a bust or a 2 card. I want the dealer to keep getting cards until the total either beats the player, or it results in a bust.

At line 211 of the javascript in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/stinkysGTI/5QZyZ/

I tried a `while` loop, but was only able to get it to run once. I was hoping to just be able to compare the 2 values. So then I tried a `do/while` loop and it went haywire. The dealer eventually busted, but not till it had a score of 80+ and then again once it had 60+!

Since the totals will be dynamic depending on cards drawn, I can't use the classic `i = 0 ... i++`. How can I go about this to get the correct outcome?

Comment: FYI.  The logic for the dealer should be: 1) If everyone else has busted, dealer takes no more cards and game is over.  2) Dealer takes cards until dealer has 17 or higher (house rules determine when dealer hits on a soft 17 or not).  It is not just that the dealer stops when they beat your hand.  The dealer must get to 17 or higher to win if the player did not bust.  Also, you are dealing random cards/suits without regard for what cards have already been played.  You could have 5 aces in a hand the way you are dealing or infinite number of face cards.

Comment: You should make a drawCard() function which returns a card from the deck.

Comment: @jfriend00 I know I haven't accounted for duplicate cards yet. As it is now, as soon as someone busts, the game ends. I know I'm not finished with all of the dealer's logic yet, this was just a part of it I was stuck on. Thank you for the info though. I actually couldn't remember if it was 17 that the dealer generally stays on.

Comment: @cgatian Yeah, I was going to clean it up when I got more of it done. I had no idea how much was going to go into it. So I was just writing chunks at a time and it got out of hand. I'll do that soon though :)

Comment: @stinkysGTI I attempted to review your code but its so procedural it makes it difficult.  Perhaps performing the refactor now would help and you might see the issue in doing so.